# Bypass squid proxy

Tags: firewall, squid, content-filter

I have a transparent squid proxy that I am using to filter out ads from web traffic which works well enough, however I would like to have the option of bypassing the proxy as well at times when I do want ads (because sometimes the blacklist is over-zealous).

Ideally this would be done by having squid listen on two different ports, and allowing clients to manually connect to the second port if they want unfiltered traffic. Is it possible to do this without requiring authentication on either port?

currently I have a firewall setup that only allows outbound traffic from the squid proxy - I could set up a second squid server and allow traffic from both, but I would prefer to configure my existing setup instead if possible.

edit: this is running on top of PFsense as a network-wide filter, just squid, no squidgaurd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends exactly on what you are using to blacklist the ADs of course.  If you are using an external tool like squidguard, then it will be somewhat difficult.

If you are doing everything with Squid ACLs, then it should be easy.  It would look something like this.  I am assuming your would have an acl named `ads_bl` that describes the ads to blacklist.

```
# listen on multiple ports
http_port 3128 transparent
http_port 8888
# acls describing the incoming port for the request on the squid.
acl bypass myport 8888
acl filterads myport 3128
# for the filter port, we don't allow the ads
http_access allow all filterads !ads_bl
# and the bypass port permits all
http_access allow all bypass
```